# Automated processing of large text file(s)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

The scenario is as follows: A large text file is put somewhere. At a certain time of the day (or manually or after x number of files), a Virtual Machine with Biztalk installed is about to start automatically for processing of these files. Then, the files should be put in some output place and the VM should be shut down. I don´t know the time it takes for processing these files.

**What is the best way to build such a solution?** The solution is preferably to be used for similar scenarios in the future.

I was thinking of Logic Apps for the workflow, blob storage or FTP for input/output of the files, an API App for starting/shutting down the VM. Can Azure Functions be used in some way?

EDIT:

I also asked the question elsewhere, see link.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19a69fe7-8e61-4b94-a3e7-b21c4c925195/automated-processing-of-large-text-files?forum=azurelogicapps

Answer (score 1):

Just create an Azure Runbook with a Schedule, make that Runbook check for specific files in a Storage Account, if they exist, start up a VM and wait till the files are gone, once the files are gone (so BizTalk processed them, deleted and put them in some place where they belong), Runbook would stop the VM.